# Is it possible to use iPad Pro as a touch screen for Macbook Pro (retina), without lag and without app such as Astropad?

Tags: mac, ipad, monitor

I would like to use my iPad Pro (Retina) as a natural extension of my Macbook's pro retina screen, without lag and keeping the touch screen functionalities. The aim is to draw directly in photoshop or other softwares using Macbook's computational power, while exploiting the iPad's touch screen + Apple Pencil.
I know there are a few apps like Duet and AstroPad that do the job, but I also know that they create a virtual screen and that the resolution becomes poor and lag increases with increasing resolution.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately.

The bigger iPad Pro has a really fast connection to your computer.

But nobody has seen fit to exploit this for its obvious ability to create a lag free input device for desktop software.

Part of this is Apple's fault, they don't make it easy to achieve, on purpose, for reasons probably to do with product line differentiation and a "we could care less" attitude towards creatives since the passing of Steve.

It's also partly to do with developers not taking the kinds of risks they might have in the past, and hacking away at jailbroken iPads to free up a more robust and rapid connection between the two computers.

It's turned out that neither Apple or devs care about digital creatives now that they've both go mainstream cool and huge audiences thanks to the iPod, iPhone and iPad.

The Mac, despite Tim Cook's protestations, is in a cycle of neglected decline that's unlikely to reverse.

Comment: Most artists that want to use a drawing table use one of the ones already established on the market. I'm pretty sure Apple doesn't see a compelling market there as it's a minority and already being served by 3rd party products. I doubt very much that it's because Tim doesn't like you.

Comment: Most artists know the iPad Pro's 240Hz claims hold water, the Pencil is extremely accurate and that Procreate's latest update is VERY good. That Concepts, Sketch Club, IbisPaint, SketchBook, Sketches, Memopad, Pixelmator, ProtoSketch and others are good. It is a great pity modern Apple only pays lip service to digital creativity. There was a long history of profound initiatives and efforts on behalf of digital creativity within old Apple. Core Graphics, Core MIDI etc. Core Animation, ironically, was one, and made iOS possible. How personal you want to make all this is entirely your choice.

Comment: People have been second-guessing Apple since the beginning of Apple. I guess that's how it will always be.

Comment: The trashcan Mac Pro "innovation", Final Cut's recent history, Aperture being canned, new iMacs using old AMD GPUs, new MacBook Pro without esc and function keys + old AMD GPUs. No meaningful connection between iPads and a computer, or file management, the MacMini's and iMacs no longer upgradeable. Adobe and Apple at a standoff for several years over app performance (Illustrator, AE and Indesign in particular), Nvidia and Apple not on speaking terms. etc etc.. Then there's Apple Watch, the AirPods fiasco and AppleTV. Second guessing? Or an obvious, observable trend?